# What happens if my GRE scores arrive after the deadline?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gre

There is a possibility that my GRE scores will reach the admission office 2 or 3 days after the specified deadline- Although the university will only start taking decision in April- Will my application be set as incomplete?

Comment: Many universities allow you to submit unofficial GRE scores (verbal and quantitative sections), and then your scores will be verified once they are received officially. Ask the admissions office.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Ask the university*. If they know your situation in advance, they will probably be able to accommodate you. Ask if you can either submit the whole application late, or if you should submit the rest of your application on time and send just the GRE score through when it arrives.

Comment: This is good advice, but I'd be willing to bet that, more often than not, an admissions office would tell an applicant to get an incomplete application submitted early rather than a full application submitted late. I think it's generally best to get on their radar as soon as you can.

Comment: @J.R. I agree there (that's why submitting the incomplete application is one of the options in my answer). The most important thing is to make the admissions people aware of your situation well in advance, so that it's clear that the delay is not due to disorganization or laziness on your part. Proactivity is always appreciated and reflects well upon the applicant.